# Запрос к двум таблицам с последующей обработкой одного результата

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую всех вошедших

Не в курсе есть ли в mysql связи. Допустим есть 2 таблицы. В одной таблице в последнем столбце у каждой выбранной строки - поле с номером, и нужно делать запрос к другой таблице, что бы узнать, что это за номер. Видел, что можно как то сделать 1 запрос для этого дела и уже перебирать результат запроса как будь то он из одной таблицы. Пример того, что пытаюсь осуществить:

```
//table `girls`
//fields - `id`,`name`,`size`
(1, 'у Маши', 4),
(2, 'у Светы', 3),
(3, 'у Оли', 2),
(4, 'у Ирины', 3);

//table `boobs`
//fields - `id`,`size`,`title`
(18, 2, 'нормальные'),
(31, 3, 'большие'),
(41, 4, 'очень большие');
```

Можно, по старинке, сделать запрос к `girls`, и перебирая записи в цикле, в самом цикле делать запросы к `boobs`, и заменять цифру из `girls`.`size` на значение `boobs`.`title`. А можно ли на выходе получить 1 таблицу?

[Сам сумел только так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bebf/10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[так?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bebf/12)

```
SELECT
  g.id, g.name,
  b1.title boobs
FROM girls g
LEFT JOIN boobs b1 ON b1.size = g.size
```

... ппц конечно темка.

```
/* Результат */
1   у Маши очень большие
2   у Светы большие
3   у Оли нормальные
4   у Ирины большие
```

Comment: Да! Оно самое! Спасибо огромное