# Можно ли указать в MySQL автоматом менять значение при запросе

Tags: php, mysql

[Немного ответвляясь от прошлой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/226756/php-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0)

Представьте, есть таблица, `id/fio/sex` (Ид/фио/пол). Туда где пол глупо записывать Мужской/Женский/'пусто' - для этого ест-но другая таблица `id/sex/title` (Ид/пол/описание). При запросе к БД для того, что бы получить пол не в виде цифры ест-но делаем запрос сразу к 2м таблицам - нет проблем.

Вопрос: Можно ли как то в самой бд указать, что бы при запросе поля `sex` (пол) из первой таблицы, автоматом подставлялось значение из другой таблицы, с определенной связью ест-но?

p.s. конечно, можно написать определенную функцию, которой будут передаваться данные для запроса, и уже она сама сработает как надо, но интересует так, как описал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем не устраивает обычный `JOIN`?

```
SELECT
  T1.id,
  T1.fio,
  T2.sex,
  T2.description
FROM
  Table1 AS T
JOIN
  Table2 AS T2
ON
  T1.sex = T2.id
WHERE
  T1.fio='vasya pupkin'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1210f/1/0)
Это можно уложить в хранимую процедуру, например, и вызывать только её

Comment: @SoWa - JOIN устраивает, не знал кстати. Но все же интересно есть ли именно такое решение, как написал.

p.s. если так нельзя, или никто больше ничего не напишет - влеплю акцепт тебе

Comment: Я добавил ссылку на SQLFiddle, там составлена схема и запрос - в таблице1 хранится пол как число, в таблице 2 - уже как текст. В выборку в поле sex попадает уже текст.

Comment: За ссылку спасибо! Сам правда уже проделал такое локально и возьму на вооружение. Просто думал что можно как то настроить связь между полями в таблицах и вообще делать такое:

    SELECT `id`,`fio`,`sex` FROM `table1`;
    // в место: `5`,`Вася`,`1`
    // будет  : `5`,`Вася`,`Мальчик`

Comment: @frank - такое можно на уровне ORM организовать

Comment: оу, круто! можно ссылку на инфу или пример. я сразу не смог нагуглить